# Header Data Template will not render graphics with custom pagination

Tags: c#, wpf, flowdocument

I implemented the following code to add headers and footers to a dynamicdocumentpaginator that I received at the following link. 
http://itquestionz.com/questions/232635/how-to-create-a-xaml-flowdocument-with-page-headers-and-footers-when-rendered-to

I have everything working properly except that the header will not render to the pages. the space for the header and footer are reserved but their is no content. any help on this would be great thank you.

Comment: Resolved I had to remove the dispatcher in the AddHeaerorFooter Method and everything worked fine.